# Is there way of installing IDEA EAP without uninstalling old version?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there way of installing IDEA EAP without uninstalling old version ? I'm trying to install version 13, but I don't want to delete 12 because Scala projects often hang IDE in 13.

May be there is some commanline parameter for installer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to keep as many versions as you want, just install them in different folders.

Uninstalling older versions is optional unless you want to install in exactly the same directory.

Comment: Thank you. And by the way installing IDEA 13 EAP from ZIP doesn'twork for me. For some reason it's missing WebServices plugin. Here is screenshot http://snag.gy/ma1vb.jpg

Comment: EAP issues should be reported directly at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. This one is probably already known.